# applying *ngFor on <li> only shows list with empty data, while fetching data from api on ngOnInit()?

Tags: angular7, ngfor

To show data obtained from Api, I applied *ngFor directive on li tag. Then, I used interpolation to show the data inside the li tag. But I am not getting any data in the list. However, the list does show exactly the same number of empty list items as the number of items available in the data obtained from API. If I log the data inside the subscribe method browser logs data obtained from api but when I log the data outside subscribe method browser logs undefined object. I have attached my codes. I will appreciate any form of help and advice.

I tried appplying *ngIf condition to only make the list visible once the data is already subscribed in ngOnInit parent ul tag of li as suggested in one of the other posts.

```
branch-list.component.ts

constructor(private service : BranchService) {  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll()
    .subscribe((data: Branch[]) => {
      this.branches = data;
      console.log(this.branches);
    });
    console.log(this.branches);
  };


branch-list.component.html

<ul class="list-group-flush" *ngIf="branches">
    <li *ngFor="let branch of branches; let serialNo = index" class="list-group-item">
      <span hidden>{{branch.Id}}</span>
      {{ serialNo+1 }}. {{ branch.BranchCode }} {{ branch.Description }}
    </li>
  </ul>
<ul>


console of browser

Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

undefined   

(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, branchCode: "KTM", description: "Kathmandu"}
1: {id: 2, branchCode: "PKH", description: "Pokhara"}
2: {id: 3, branchCode: "HTD", description: "Hetauda"}
3: {id: 4, branchCode: "MHN", description: "Mahendranagar"}
4: {id: 5, branchCode: "JHP", description: "Jhapa"}
5: {id: 6, branchCode: "KTM", description: "Kathmandu"}
6: {id: 7, branchCode: "PTN", description: "PTN"}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The list is supposed to show the data as logged in the console.Console logs data as expected. But in the page, empty list is shown. The empty list only updates and shows the value of serial no but both branchcode and descriptions are blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially set branches = null;

Instead of performing API call in **ngOnInIt** try in ** ngAfterViewInit** - place where DOM is rendered

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.service.getAll()
    .subscribe((data: Branch[]) => {
      this.branches = [...data];
      console.log(this.branches);
    });
  };
```

```
<ul class="list-group-flush" *ngIf="branches && branches.length">
    <li *ngFor="let branch of branches; let serialNo = index" class="list-group-item">
      {{ serialNo+1 }}. {{ branch.BranchCode }} {{ branch.Description }}
    </li>
  </ul>
<ul>
```

With my understanding i think would work try and update

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I followed your suggestion but still the result is the same.

Comment: @RoshanDangol can u plz share console screen output, your dom output and also your network output.
also please try this <ul><ng-container *ngIf="branches "> li code with your templates </ng-container></ul> and remove ngif for ul

Comment: if that is not working please add your code in plunker. lets validate @RoshanDangol

Comment: prakash r, thank you so much for your help. Changing the properties branch.BranchCode and branch.Description from pascalcase to camelcase (branch.branchCode) solved the problem. In the branch model I have used pascal case to name properties, but the browser logs them in camelcases. So, I tried changing the case and it worked. Can you provide some suggestion or conventions to avoid this?

Comment: @RoshanDangol Issue is from server side. U need to Serialize The Object From Server Side And Pass The Same To Client. The issue will be resolved. The right place to do this operation is server side.

Comment: Thanks a lot I did as you told on the server side.